# How do I send a message over a network?

Tags: java, networking, client-server

I want to be able to send a simple message across a network.  Any message.

Specifically, I want a server that's running all the time, and a client that can connect to and communicate with the server on demand.

I don't know where to begin.  What is the simplest way to send a message over a network?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I up-voted this question and here's why:  This is actually a very clear and discreet question.  He's asking for a very simple thing, `How do I send a message over a network`  There might be numerous ways to do this, but that's fine, so long as an answer with just one way satisfies the problem.

Comment: The server should be multi-threaded, doesn't have to be but might be easier, and should always be listening for new connections. When it receives a new connection put it into a new thread, to go do its business, and then listen for another connection. Look for tutorials out there, you'll figure it out. By practicing and trying new techniques you will find what works and what doesn't. The option I listed above is just one of many solutions to go about your project. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the tutorial [Reading from and Writing to a Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html), you could start with a simple [echo server](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/84network/EchoServer.java.html) which uses a [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) like so

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  // create socket
  int port = 4444;
  ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
  System.err.println("Started server on port " + port);

  // repeatedly wait for connections, and process
  while (true) {
    // a "blocking" call which waits until a connection is requested
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.err.println("Accepted connection from client");

    // open up IO streams
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    // waits for data and reads it in until connection dies
    // readLine() blocks until the server receives a new line from
    // client
    String s;
    try {
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(s);
            out.flush();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // close IO streams, then socket
    System.err.println("Closing connection with client");
    out.close();
    in.close();
    clientSocket.close();
}
```

Then you can use "telnet localhost 4444" to test it, or write an entire client; perhaps like the client in the tutorial above.

Comment: now how do i make a client to conect to that? XD

Comment: @user3170707 [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/EchoClient.java).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this question is really open.  First there are a few questions to answer: Do you want to implement your own server or use an existing technology. The JMS - API oviously would be a starting point in the later case. There exist many implementation providers, the reference implementation within Glassfish itself, HornetQ both standalone or as part of a JBoss - Instance, just to name two. Sending messages with JMS is pretty straight forward when understanding some basic concepts and they can contain both textual and binary data.
Another way of using existing solution is to implement a WebService your client can connect to, wich would be the JAX-RS for REST - based WebServices e.g. This approach is also more platform - independend, as of this writing I don't know a library for Android clients supporting the JMS, and most of the other programming language have full support for REST - based services. When you don't want to use any existing protocoll, though, you have to stick with an own implementation of a server and client. So this would be the mentioned socket - programming. Well, this task won't be to easy: You would won't your server to handle multiple clients at the same time, not blocking one request until another one is finished, provide some mechanism for authorizing your client for application access against the server. You will propably have resources that are shared between your clients on the server when handling multiple clients simutanliously so the access to this resources must be synchronized, these topics relate to concurrent programming and is a quiet interesting field of information technology of its own. Other intersting aspects of your application design could be decisions as using an supporting the JNDI for resource binding or implementing a CDI - container so that clients can easily adapt your message exchanging format. It's fun, but not a within - one - day - task. ;)